# Quick clarification on const pointers

Tags: c, pointers, constants

This should be a pretty straightforward question. I'm brushing up on my C and want to make sure I'm understanding const pointers correctly.

Say I have a function `static void penv(const char * const * envp)`; I think this reads as "penv takes a pointer envp to a const pointer to a const char". Is this correct?

Comment: My advice is to avoid using `const` pointers directly. Instead write typedefs, like `typedef const char* LPCSTR;`. Then it's obvious at first glance what is const and what is not. Clarity of code is usually the most important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule says that **const** should apply to what comes before it, but there's a syntactic sugar:

```
const char
```

is equivalent to

```
char const
```

thus the reading is:

*"penv takes a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant char"*

Thus you're correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.

The trick is to read the declaration backwards (right-to-left):

```
static void penv(const char * const * envp);
```

Here, `envp` is a pointer (`const char * const *`) that points to a constant pointer (`const char * const`), which points to a constant char (`const char`).

Comment: FYI, the verb is, "to point", not, " to pointer"

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "const pointer", it is not clear if you mean that the pointer is constant, or the thing to which it points.

Just read the type backwards (and realize that `const char` and `char const` are the same thing.

In this case, `envp` is a pointer (not constant) to a constant pointer to a constant `char`.

I.e. `envp` can be set to point elsewhere, but the pointer(s) to which it points cannot be modified, and neither can the `char`(s) to which they point.